# Some normal updates killed my sound device

Tags: sound, updates, pulseaudio

I am a plain vanilla pulseaudio user. No special settings.

Been using kubuntu 18.04 with good audio on this notebook for years.

A month or two ago, a kernel update broke my audio, so I reverted to the previous kernel until the next one came out which worked again.

I just installed some normal updates on my system and audio no longer works.

I don't reboot very often - unless an update requires it, so I'm not sure if something broke, but didn't manifest until I had to reboot for the new kernel.

How can I fix this?

I just rebooted and my audio is gone. The device disappeared. (kubuntu
18.04 Intel 64-bit)

It was working fine earlier yesterday.

I tried going back to the previous kernel.

I tried a couple of previous versions of linux-firmware.

dmesg shows this

```
[Tue Jul 14 11:40:17 2020] snd_hda_codec_conexant hdaudioC1D0: CX20756:
BIOS auto-probing.
[Tue Jul 14 11:40:17 2020] snd_hda_codec_conexant hdaudioC1D0:
autoconfig for CX20756: line_outs=1 (0x17/0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0) type:speak$
[Tue Jul 14 11:40:17 2020] snd_hda_codec_conexant hdaudioC1D0:   
speaker_outs=0 (0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0)
[Tue Jul 14 11:40:17 2020] snd_hda_codec_conexant hdaudioC1D0:   
hp_outs=1 (0x16/0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0)
[Tue Jul 14 11:40:17 2020] snd_hda_codec_conexant hdaudioC1D0:    mono:
mono_out=0x0
[Tue Jul 14 11:40:17 2020] snd_hda_codec_conexant hdaudioC1D0:    inputs:
[Tue Jul 14 11:40:17 2020] snd_hda_codec_conexant hdaudioC1D0:     
Internal Mic=0x1a
[Tue Jul 14 11:40:17 2020] snd_hda_codec_conexant hdaudioC1D0:      Mic=0x19
[Tue Jul 14 11:40:17 2020] snd_hda_codec_conexant hdaudioC1D0: Enable
sync_write for stable communication
[Tue Jul 14 11:40:17 2020] input: HDA Intel PCH Mic as
/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card1/input15
[Tue Jul 14 11:40:17 2020] input: HDA Intel PCH Headphone as
/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card1/input16
[Tue Jul 14 11:40:17 2020] input: HDA Intel HDMI HDMI/DP,pcm=3 as
/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:03.0/sound/card0/input17
[Tue Jul 14 11:40:17 2020] input: HDA Intel HDMI HDMI/DP,pcm=7 as
/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:03.0/sound/card0/input18
[Tue Jul 14 11:40:17 2020] input: HDA Intel HDMI HDMI/DP,pcm=8 as
/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:03.0/sound/card0/input19
[Tue Jul 14 11:40:17 2020] input: HDA Intel HDMI HDMI/DP,pcm=9 as
/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:03.0/sound/card0/input20
[Tue Jul 14 11:40:17 2020] input: HDA Intel HDMI HDMI/DP,pcm=10 as
/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:03.0/sound/card0/input21
```

That's a whole lot of zeroes, but I don't know what it looks like when
it works.

I tried playing an mp3 and Amarok says no device - falling back to default.

System Settings only shows default. There's usually an analog device and
a digital (HDMI) device.

I went through my package history and nothing else jumps out at me.

```
bigbird@sananda:~/sandbox$ pulseaudio --check
bigbird@sananda:~/sandbox$ echo $?
1
bigbird@sananda:~/sandbox$ pulseaudio --start
E: [pulseaudio] main.c: Daemon startup failed.
```

Nope, it's not running and it doesn't want to either.

```
bigbird@sananda:~/sandbox$ export PULSE_LOG=99
bigbird@sananda:~/sandbox$ pulseaudio --start
D: [pulseaudio] caps.c: Cleaning up privileges.
D: [pulseaudio] conf-parser.c: Parsing configuration file '/etc/pulse/daemon.conf'
D: [pulseaudio] conf-parser.c: /etc/pulse/daemon.conf.d does not exist, ignoring.
D: [pulseaudio] conf-parser.c: Parsing configuration file '/etc/pulse/client.conf'
D: [pulseaudio] conf-parser.c: /etc/pulse/client.conf.d does not exist, ignoring.
E: [pulseaudio] main.c: Daemon startup failed.

bigbird@sananda:/etc/pulse$ ls
client.conf  daemon.conf  default.pa  default.pa.dpkg-old  system.pa
```

So, I have .conf files, but no conf.d files.

```
bigbird@sananda:/etc/pulse$ pulseaudio -vvvvv
D: [pulseaudio] caps.c: Cleaning up privileges.
D: [pulseaudio] conf-parser.c: Parsing configuration file '/etc/pulse/daemon.conf'
D: [pulseaudio] conf-parser.c: /etc/pulse/daemon.conf.d does not exist, ignoring.
I: [pulseaudio] main.c: setrlimit(RLIMIT_NICE, (31, 31)) failed: Operation not permitted
I: [pulseaudio] main.c: setrlimit(RLIMIT_RTPRIO, (9, 9)) failed: Operation not permitted
D: [pulseaudio] core-rtclock.c: Timer slack is set to 50 us.
D: [pulseaudio] core-util.c: RealtimeKit worked.
I: [pulseaudio] core-util.c: Successfully gained nice level -11.
I: [pulseaudio] main.c: This is PulseAudio 11.1
D: [pulseaudio] main.c: Compilation host: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
D: [pulseaudio] main.c: Compilation CFLAGS: -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/pulseaudio-3lFkjS/pulseaudio-11.1=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wall -W -Wextra -pipe -Wno-long-long -Wno-overlength-strings -Wunsafe-loop-optimizations -Wundef -Wformat=2 -Wlogical-op -Wsign-compare -Wformat-security -Wmissing-include-dirs -Wformat-nonliteral -Wpointer-arith -Winit-self -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wfloat-equal -Wmissing-prototypes -Wredundant-decls -Wmissing-declarations -Wmissing-noreturn -Wshadow -Wendif-labels -Wcast-align -Wstrict-aliasing -Wwrite-strings -Wno-unused-parameter -ffast-math -fno-common -fdiagnostics-show-option -fdiagnostics-color=auto
D: [pulseaudio] main.c: Running on host: Linux x86_64 4.15.0-109-generic #110-Ubuntu SMP Tue Jun 23 02:39:32 UTC 2020
D: [pulseaudio] main.c: Found 4 CPUs.
I: [pulseaudio] main.c: Page size is 4096 bytes
D: [pulseaudio] main.c: Compiled with Valgrind support: no
D: [pulseaudio] main.c: Running in valgrind mode: no
D: [pulseaudio] main.c: Running in VM: no
D: [pulseaudio] main.c: Optimized build: yes
D: [pulseaudio] main.c: FASTPATH defined, only fast path asserts disabled.
I: [pulseaudio] main.c: Machine ID is 02069b02445e453a99fc7b9858bb4a27.
I: [pulseaudio] main.c: Session ID is 3.
I: [pulseaudio] main.c: Using runtime directory /run/user/1000/pulse.
I: [pulseaudio] main.c: Using state directory /home/bigbird/.config/pulse.
I: [pulseaudio] main.c: Using modules directory /usr/lib/pulse-11.1/modules.
I: [pulseaudio] main.c: Running in system mode: no
I: [pulseaudio] main.c: System supports high resolution timers
D: [pulseaudio] memblock.c: Using shared memfd memory pool with 1024 slots of size 64.0 KiB each, total size is 64.0 MiB, maximum usable slot size is 65472
I: [pulseaudio] cpu-x86.c: CPU flags: CMOV MMX SSE SSE2 SSE3 SSSE3 SSE4_1 SSE4_2
I: [pulseaudio] svolume_mmx.c: Initialising MMX optimized volume functions.
I: [pulseaudio] remap_mmx.c: Initialising MMX optimized remappers.
I: [pulseaudio] svolume_sse.c: Initialising SSE2 optimized volume functions.
I: [pulseaudio] remap_sse.c: Initialising SSE2 optimized remappers.
I: [pulseaudio] sconv_sse.c: Initialising SSE2 optimized conversions.
I: [pulseaudio] svolume_orc.c: Initialising ORC optimized volume functions.
W: [pulseaudio] module-equalizer-sink.c: module-equalizer-sink is currently unsupported, and can sometimes cause PulseAudio crashes, increased latency or audible artifacts.
W: [pulseaudio] module-equalizer-sink.c: If you're facing audio problems, try unloading this module as a potential workaround.
E: [pulseaudio] module-equalizer-sink.c: Master sink not found
E: [pulseaudio] module.c: Failed to load module "module-equalizer-sink" (argument: ""): initialization failed.
E: [pulseaudio] main.c: Module load failed.
E: [pulseaudio] main.c: Failed to initialize daemon.
I: [pulseaudio] main.c: Daemon terminated.

bigbird@sananda:/etc/pulse$ aplay -l
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
Parsing configuration file '/etc/pulse/client.conf'
/etc/pulse/client.conf.d does not exist, ignoring.
Using shared memfd memory pool with 1024 slots of size 64.0 KiB each, total size is 64.0 MiB, maximum usable slot size is 65472
Trying to connect to /run/user/1000/pulse/native...
connect(): No such file or directory (2)
Trying to connect to /var/run/pulse/native...
connect(): No such file or directory (2)
Trying to autospawn...
D: [pulseaudio] caps.c: Cleaning up privileges.
D: [pulseaudio] conf-parser.c: Parsing configuration file '/etc/pulse/daemon.conf'
D: [pulseaudio] conf-parser.c: /etc/pulse/daemon.conf.d does not exist, ignoring.
card 0: HDMI [HDA Intel HDMI], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: HDMI [HDA Intel HDMI], device 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: HDMI [HDA Intel HDMI], device 8: HDMI 2 [HDMI 2]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: HDMI [HDA Intel HDMI], device 9: HDMI 3 [HDMI 3]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: HDMI [HDA Intel HDMI], device 10: HDMI 4 [HDMI 4]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: CX20756 Analog [CX20756 Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
bigbird@sananda:/etc/pulse$ cd
bigbird@sananda:~$ ls .pulse
ls: cannot access '.pulse': No such file or directory
bigbird@sananda:~$ ls .config/pulse
02069b02445e453a99fc7b9858bb4a27-card-database.tdb   0be654d3d90b45c69c8747978a3a29fc-device-volumes.tdb
02069b02445e453a99fc7b9858bb4a27-default-sink        0be654d3d90b45c69c8747978a3a29fc-runtime
02069b02445e453a99fc7b9858bb4a27-default-source      0be654d3d90b45c69c8747978a3a29fc-stream-volumes.tdb
02069b02445e453a99fc7b9858bb4a27-device-manager.tdb  cookie
02069b02445e453a99fc7b9858bb4a27-device-volumes.tdb  default.pa
02069b02445e453a99fc7b9858bb4a27-runtime             equalizer-presets.tdb
02069b02445e453a99fc7b9858bb4a27-stream-volumes.tdb  equalizer-state.tdb
0be654d3d90b45c69c8747978a3a29fc-card-database.tdb   equalizerrc
0be654d3d90b45c69c8747978a3a29fc-default-sink        equalizerrc.availablepresets
0be654d3d90b45c69c8747978a3a29fc-default-source      presets
0be654d3d90b45c69c8747978a3a29fc-device-manager.tdb
bigbird@sananda:~$
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- It seems HDMI audio is the default device (usually bad) :
  Install pavucontrol(Pulseaudio volume control),
  In  **configuration** tab, check  "profile" is not set to HDMI but to analog.
  Also in **output device tab**, click on the green button near "internal audio" to make it default.
  Next step is alsamixer to check muted faders at Alsa level: (F6 to select sound device).
  Look [here](https://itsfoss.com/fix-sound-ubuntu-1304-quick-tip/) for more details.
- Edit for pulseaudio error: try this command
  `mv ~/.config/pulse ~/.config/pulseold`
  then reboot
- if not ok,  try this command to see if a process locks the audio device:
  `sudo fuser -v /dev/snd/*`

Comment: Just tried this. It says connection to PulseAudio failed. And when I run `start-pulseaudio-x11`, it says Connection failure: Connection refused
pa_context_connect() failed: Connection refused.

Comment: edit for pulseaudio config reset

Comment: Getting rid of `~/.config/pulse` and rebooting fixed it. Thanks! I took a quick look and the old directory has 20 files including some equalizer files and an empty presets subdirectory - including a couple of broken symlinks into `/tmp` (probably caused by rebooting) in it while the new one only has six. I don't know enough about pulseaudio configuration to go much deeper.